# The tool thin_delta segfaulting

Tags: lvm, thin-provisioning

I am trying to run thin_delta and it is segfaulting.

OS : CentOS 7.

```
Cmd:
/usr/sbin/pdata_tools thin_delta --verbose --thin1 1 --thin2 2 /dev/mapper/vg_root_thin_pool_tmeta
```

I have a thin volume and two snapshots for the thin volume.

The configuration is same as [server fault question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/733150/figure-out-the-used-space-on-the-snapshot-thin-volume)

Please let me know if I need to write down the configuration as part of this question and I will do so.

The command segfaults. Could you please provide a example of how to use the command.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to report a bug to CentOS then, not us.  Also segregating has nothing to do with segfaulting.

Comment: I wanted to know if the command is syntactically correct.

Comment: Whether it is or is not, the program is not supposed to segfault.